I can’t change the color of SVG icons in action/symbolic
When I try to change the color of SVG icons in action/symbolic and reload the icons, the new color doesn't appear.
I'm using Bloom icons and also we10x icons.
I've tried this in:
usr/share/icons/bloom/scalable/action/
and also in
hom/local/share/icons/bloom/scalable/action/
and also in
home/icons/bloom/scalable/action/
The new color only appears in the icon folder but doesn't show up when reloading the system
Operating system : ubuntu 22.4 ltc
distro : Zorin OS 17.2
DE:Gnome 43.9
How can I do this?

Zorin OS is not supported in Ask Ubuntu
